# Iterate through directories beginning with specific letter and execute batch script

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, gnu-make

I have lot of directories which begins with UT_ (UT_abc, UT_def, UT_ghi, ...).
I would like to go into each of these directories and execute a command (a makefile). I tried this:

```
FOR /f %%p IN ("UT_*") DO make "%%p" /s /q
```

But it doesn't work. Also, in each of these UT_xyz directories, there exist one directory and than the content. For example:

```
UT_abc\directoryabc\makefile
UT_def\directorydef\makefile
UT_ghi\directoryghi\makefile
```

....
 Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're [parsing](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) the literal string `"UT*"`.

Use [normal directory enumeration](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) and pass the path correctly to `make`:

```
FOR /d %%p IN (UT_*) do FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do make --directory "%%s" /s /q
```

Or change workdir to that directory:

```
FOR /d %%p IN (UT_*) do FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do pushd "%%~dpnxs" & make /s /q & popd
```